Is every finite simple group contained in a group of the form $\operatorname{PSL}(n,p)$?
$\DeclareMathOperator\Aut{Aut}\DeclareMathOperator\PSL{PSL}$Is every finite simple group contained in a group of the form $\PSL(n,p)$ for some integer $n\ge 1$ and prime $p$?
More generally, I'd like to understand how general the subgroups of $\Aut(A)$ for $A$ finite abelian can be. The relation with the titular question is that the composition factors of $\Aut(A)$ are all either abelian or of the form $\PSL(n,p)$.

Every finite group embeds into a finite symmetric group (a group acts on itself by left multiplication), so it is enough to answer for $S_n$, no?

@SamHopkins, re, in fact in $\operatorname A_n$, since they're all perfect (except for the cyclic groups of order $p$, which can easily be handled separately).

This MSE question discusses embeddings of all finite groups in many classes of finite groups, but doesn't directly mention projective special linear groups (probably not hard to achieve though): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27132

@SamHopkins, re, for a simple group that is not cyclic (and so is perfect), an embedding in $\operatorname{GL}(n, p)$ lands in $\operatorname{SL}(n, p)$; and then the pre-image of the scalar matrices is a cyclic, normal, hence trivial, subgroup, so that the composition with the projection to $\operatorname{PSL}(n, p)$ remains an embedding.  (I assume $\operatorname{PSL}(n, p)$ always means $\operatorname{SL}(n, p)$ modulo its scalar matrices, hence, say, equals $\operatorname{SL}(n, p)$ if $n$ equals $p$.)

Every finite group of order $n$ embeds into $S_n$, which embeds into $\mathrm{Alt}{n+2}$, which in turn embeds (in the obvious way) into $\mathrm{PSL}{n+2}(p)$ for every prime $p$.

This has really been answered in comments, but it is possible to go a bit further. Every finite group (simple or not) of order $n \geq 3$ embeds as a subgroup of the alternating group $A_{n+2}$ (embed it via Cayley into the obviously labelled  copy of $S_{n}$ inside $S_{n+2}$, and adjoin the transposition $(n+1\ \ n+2)$ to each odd permutation arising). Now for any prime $p$, the alternating group $A_{n+2}$ embeds naturally in ${\rm GL}(n+2,p)$. But by the simplicity of $A_{n+2},$ all permutation matrices appearing must have determinant one, and it is also clear that no  non-identity permutation matrix is scalar, so that $A_{n+2}$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm PSL}(n+2,p)$. Hence every finite group of order $n \geq 3$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm PSL}(n+2,p)$ for every prime $p$.

Why $n \ge 3$? And more characters.

@LSpice: I nearly added that $n \geq 3$ was just for ease of exposition, using the simplicity of $A_{n+2}$. Clearly groups of order $2$ embed into ${\rm PSL}(4,p)$ by inspection, but the fact that  $A_{4}$ is not simple would necessitate rewording the proof.

You don't need simplicity of the alternating groups in any case.  The sign of a permutation is the determinant of its permutation matrix.  So the even permutations of N letters all map into the special linear group of order N.

A simple group of order $n\ge 3$ embeds into $\mathrm{Alt}_n$ (this holds for every group of order not $2$ mod $4$), which in turn embeds into $\mathrm{PSL}_n(p)$ for every $p$.

Or note that $A_n$ is the commutator of $S_n$, so ends up in the commutator of $GL(n,p)$, which is contained in $SL(n,p)$. Since $Z(S_n)=1$, it must miss all scalar matrices.
